# Magento 1.3 - Left Hand Menu

Tags: php, magento, templates, menu, catalog

I'm wondering does anybody have a solution to enable the left hand menu in Magento 1.3. I've located the file i would like to use at

```
design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml
```

but am unsure how to customise my template to enable it. The tutorials i've found seem to relate to earlier versions of magento.

EDIT- I tried that solution but it only moves the callout elements in my view, the catelog menu still appears at the top of the page and not on the left hand pane.

Comment: in the catalog.xml try changing the reference ='right' to 'left' , would be good if you posted some of your code too....

Comment: I could tell you how to do it in 1.2.1 if you like. Unfortunately I don't have the 1.3 version to test the procedure though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the page layout template to enable the left bar menu, This can be be done in admin , CMS -> Manage Pages  ... change the layout to '...with left bar' option.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the template in the layout XML file.

Comment: Not so effective, could you provide more detail?